# OSX link preview on one-time link

Tags: macos, email, force-touch

As part of a password reset process, it's not uncommon to send out a one-time link that will expire once clicked, or similarly activation links. We're seeing an issue where a user accidentally Force Touches a preview and expires the reset link in OSX Mail, thereby being unable to click the link to complete the form in a browser. Is there any way to prevent this preview behaviour to stop this happening? I found this similar question asked on the Apple forums but with no answer.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7150121

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is impossible. This feature is baked into the very core of OS X and unless there is an option in Settings.app there is now way to disable it.

Also there is no specific header or user agent set so you could determine on server-side.

Unfortunately the answer seems to be no.

**EDIT**
In the comments we came up with a JavaScript workaround. Since the force-click preview does not execute JavaScript, you could do the actual resetting process using AJAX or view a JavaScript redirection on a different page.

Comment: Thanks Julian, not the answer I wanted, but confirmed my thoughts at least. I might look to see if JavaScript is triggered, if not we can probably use a callback.

Comment: A short test (`document.write` in onload) sadly turns out that JS is not called...

Comment: Sadly? That's what we want, only invoke JS when in the browser, not in the quick look preview.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! I was thinking of a JS detection mechanism or something like that. Sometimes beauty hides behind simplicity ;) Let's read `s̶a̶d̶l̶y̶` in my comment above